# django 1.5 multiple joins

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-admin

I have 3 tables that I wish to show relate to each other with a 4th table name Pivot

```
# Manufacturer
id | name
```

---

```
# Product
id |name
```

---

```
# Part 
id| name
```

---

```
# Pivot
id | part_name_fk | product_name_fk | manufacturer_name_fk
```

---

... and a 5th table that will reference "Pivot"

```
# Report 
id |pivot_record_fk|this_week_use
```

---

Is this the correct way to "relate" three entities, if so how would I display it in admin showing all the related entries ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have it structured like so.

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, related_name="products")

class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="parts")

class Report(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, related_name="reports")
    this_week_use
```

Then in Report you can filter out based on the part's name (if you needed to) by using:

```
Report.objects.filter(manufacturer__product__part__name="Nail")
```

As for the admin, you can add have it display the different properties of it by adding methods to the ReportAdmin class and then referencing them in the list_display property. You can also add them to the [list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) so that you can filter out by values.